Can a function have a inflection point at somewhere non-differentiable?
Imagine this function :
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
    x^2,\quad x<0 \\ 
    \sqrt{x},\quad x\ge0.
\end{cases}
$$
In my lecture, my professor told me $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$ but $f(x)$ has an inflection point at $x=0$.
I get the idea that when $x<0$, $f(x)$ is concave up and when $x>0$, $f(x)$ concaves down; but I believe that if $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$, then $0$ fails the definition of being an inflection point.
For context, this is how "inflection point" and concavity" is defined in my course:

Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined on open interval $I$.
We say that $f$ concave-up on $I$ when $f'$ is increasing on $I$.
We say that $f$ is concave-down on $I$ when $f'$ is decreasing on $I$.
Let $c$ be an interior point to $I$.
We say that has an inflection point at $c$ when
"$f$ changes concavity at $c$".
We say "$f$ changes concavity at $c$" when $\exists\delta > 0$ such that
$f$ is concave-up on $[c-δ,c]$ and
concave-down on $[c,c+ δ]$
or vice versa.

So according to the definition, an inflection point must be differentiable because

it is defined within a context of a differentiable interval;
it is defined as a point when $f'$ is increasing on a small CLOSED interval with $c$ being the right endpoint and decreasing on a small CLOSED interval with $c$ being the left endpoint (or vice versa).

Both of these conditions require $f'$ to be defined at $c$ which means $f$ is differentiable at $c$.
However, for my $f(x)$ it is not differentiable at $c=0$.
The definition of an inflection point on Wikipedia also requires $f'$ to be defined at that point:

For example, the graph of the differentiable function has an inflection point at $(x, f(x))$ if and only if its first derivative $f'$ has an isolated extremum at $x$. (this is not the same as saying that $f$ has an extremum). That is, in some neighborhood, $x$ is the one and only point at which $f'$ has a (local) minimum or maximum.

So what do u guys think? Further more, consider this function: $$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}.$$
It's also non-differentiable at $0$ but concave up when negative and concave up when negative. Would you consider $0$ an inflection point?
Are there any alternative, more rigorous definitions of concavity that can handle these cases?

The problem is that your $f$ is not differentiable, but your definitions seems to require this.  So, the definitions do not even apply.

To your second question, I've seen different definitions of inflection point, some that only require continuity of $f$.  For such nuances you have to know what your instructor thinks the right definition is.  It's not an important enough thing for most people to care about, honestly.  (No one is doing cutting edge research in Calculus or analysis that would suddenly be invalidated if someone had a different definition of inflection point.)

There are several different definitions that can be found in textbooks. See the following for more details: George M. Ewing, On the definition of inflection point (1938); A. W. Walker, What is a point of inflection? (1956); Andrew M. Bruckner, Some nonequivalent definitions of inflection points (1962); Temple H. Fay, Convex functions (1998).

There's a flaw in the definition.

Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined on open interval $I$.
We say that $f$ concave-up on $I$ when ...

This gives us definitions of concavity on an open interval.

We say "$f$ changes concavity at $c$" when $∃δ>0$ such that
$f$ is concave-up on $[c-δ,c]$   and
concave-down on $[c,c+ δ]$
or vice versa.

This requires concavity to be defined on a closed interval.
But we only have a definition of concavity on open intervals.
A logical extension of the definition of concavity on open intervals to concavity on closed intervals would be that a function is concave up (for example) on a closed interval if it is concave-up on an open interval containing the closed interval.
But that definition would prevent any function from having an inflection point.
In fact, as written, the definition makes no sense, because if a function is concave-up on an interval we would like to say it is concave-up on ever point of that interval.
But then we have a definition that says $f$ must be both concave-up and concave-down at $c$ in order to have an inflection point at $c$.
When you look at it closely, it doesn't appear that we can even use this definition to conclude that $f=x^3$ has an inflection point at $c=0$.
All of these problems with the definitions are instantly cleared up if you change the closed intervals to open intervals. It seems likely that someone just made a mistake typesetting the intervals $[c-δ,c]$   and $[c,c+ δ]$; they should have used round brackets.

The french version of Wikipedia https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_d%27inflexion is a bit less restrictive concerning the regularity assumptions on $f.$
In the sequel, "locally at $x_0$" means "on some interval centered at $x_0$".
Assume that $f$ is locally defined and continuous at $x_0$, that $f$ has a tangent at $x_0$, eventually a vertical one (so that $f$ is not necessarily differentiable at $x_0$), that $f$ is twice left-differentiable and twice right-differentiable locally at $x_0$, and finally that $x_0$ is locally the only possible point satisfying $f''(x)=0.$
Then the three following conditions are equivalent, and thus any of them may be taken as a definition for $x_0$ to being a flex point:

the concavity of $f$ changes at $x_0$

the graph of $f$ cuts the tangent at $x_0$

the sign of $f''$ changes at $x_0$ ($f''(x_0)$ may exist or not).


In your case, $f$ presumably satisfy all the required conditions (i didn't check)

The vertical "tangent" at the origin to the OPs function is not a tangent in any formal sense since it is not a locally good approximation for negative $x$. To say "$f$ has a tangent at $0$" is equivalent to its smoothness  there - so for example $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ has a (vertical) tangent at the origin.

The main point is that one can define convexity/concavity without reference to the derivative at all, although your text does not do so. A function $f$ is convex [resp., concave] on an interval if for all $a$ and $b$ in the interval the line segment between $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ lies above [resp., below] the graph of $f$.
A point $c$ is an inflection point (whether $f$ is differentiable at $c$ or not) if the function is convex on some interval $(a,c)$ and concave on some interval $(c,b)$ or vice versa.
It is a fun exercise to show that if $f$ is convex (or concave) on some open interval, then it is necessarily continuous on that interval.
